# Как вычислить сумму ряда? С++

Tags: c++, математика, visual-studio-2019, ряды

Как вычислить суму ряда данной формулы на С++?????[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int sum = 1; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классический приём для вычисления подобных сумм состоит в том, чтобы последовательно сократить все члены ряда, кроме разве лишь конечного числа (обычно первого и последнего).

Для этого общий член ряда `1/n * 1/(n+1)` нужно представить в виде суммы двух дробей, в данном случае это можно сделать в силу того, что знаменатель раскладывается на множители. Вот так: `a/n + b/(n+1)`. Но как найти `a` и `b`? Сложим эти две дроби обратно: `(a*(n+1)+b*n)/(n*(n+1))`. Теперь, если присмотреться, то видно, что `a=1` и `b=-1`. Таким образом, общий член ряда равен `1/n - 1/(n+1)`. И ваш ряд превращается... превращается ваш ряд в:

```
sum (1/n * 1/(n+1)) = sum (1/n - 1/(n+1)) = 1/1-1/2 + 1/2-1/3 + 1/3-1/4 + ...
```

Видите, соседние члены полностью сокращаются. Остаётся `1 - lim (1/(n+1))`, то есть `1`.

Программа в вашем случае будет выглядеть так (только главная функция):

```
int main () {
  cout << '1' << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Если ваш преподаватель не примет такое элегантное решение, то попросите его написать лучше, а мы посмотрим :)